# What is iproxy.saverpigeeks.com

Tags: proxy, phishing

I'm seeing it in a ton of search results and even copy pasted into content on this site (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687289/adding-a-bookmark-link-to-a-facebook-iframe-app).  Is it a phishing thing or just some actual proxy thing that is innocent?

A [link to the proxy's homepage](http://iproxy.saverpigeeks.com).

Answer (score 0):

It humorously? hacks the text that comes to you from a site that you reach through it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a proxy. It also appears to impersonate the site rather deeply, simply inserting `iproxy.saverpigeeks.com` after the domain name.

I would guess it's trying to artificially raise it's page rank, but it while it has search results it doesn't have a PR.